# How do I prevent Maven from assmebling my WAR if my integration tests fail?

Tags: maven, maven-3, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

I’m using Maven 3.3.3 with Java 8 on Mac Yosemite.  I have a bunch of integration tests and I have my failsafe plugin (v 2.18.1) set up as such …

```
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.18.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                                    <argLine>-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -noverify -XX:-UseSplitVerifier ${itCoverageAgent}</argLine>
                                    <skipTests>${skipAllTests}</skipTests>
                            </configuration>
                            <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                    </execution>
                            </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

However, when I run the command “mvn clean install,” even when I have failed unit tests, the build continues on to assembling the war.  How do I prevent further Maven activity if I have failed integration tests?  Below is example output of what I’m seeing.  Note that the WAR plugin continues to run even after the tests have failed.

```
Results :

Failed tests: 
  MyProjectInstantLoginControllerIT.testInstantLoginSuccessNoCredentailsObj:245 View name is not equal to 'redirect:http://localhost:80/authenticate' but was 'redirect:http://localhost:80/home'
  MyProjectInstantLoginControllerIT.testInstantLoginSuccessStudent:153 View name is not equal to 'redirect:http://localhost:80/authenticate' but was 'redirect:http://localhost:80/home'
  MyProjectInstantLoginControllerIT.testInstantLoginSuccessTeacher:125 View name is not equal to 'redirect:http://localhost:80/authenticate' but was 'redirect:http://localhost:80/home'
  MyProjectInstantLoginControllerIT.testInstantLoginSuccessWithApacheHeader:187 View name is not equal to 'redirect:http://localhost:80/authenticate' but was 'redirect:http://localhost:80/home'
Tests in error: 
  ClassController2IT.testUpdateClassWoSchedule:478->AbstractClassControllerTest.submitCreateClassForm:514 » LazyInitialization

Tests run: 157, Failures: 4, Errors: 1, Skipped: 4

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ my-module ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [my-module] in [/Users/davea/Documents/my_workspace/my-module/target/my-module]
[INFO] Dependency [Dependency {groupId=org.mainco.subco, artifactId=second-module, version=87.0.0-SNAPSHOT, type=jar}] has changed (was Dependency {groupId=org.mainco.subco, artifactId=second-module, version=87.0.0-SNAPSHOT, type=jar}).
[WARNING] File to remove [/Users/davea/Documents/my_workspace/my-module/target/my-module/WEB-INF/lib/second-module-87.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar] has not been found
[INFO] Dependency [Dependency {groupId=org.springframework, artifactId=spring-core, version=3.2.11.RELEASE, type=jar}] has changed (was Dependency {groupId=org.springframework, artifactId=spring-core, version=3.2.11.RELEASE, type=jar}).
[WARNING] File to remove [/Users/davea/Documents/my_workspace/my-module/target/my-module/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar] has not been found
[INFO] Dependency [Dependency {groupId=org.springframework.security.extensions, artifactId=spring-security-saml2-core, version=1.0.0.RC2, type=jar}] has changed (was Dependency {groupId=org.springframework.security.extensions, artifactId=spring-security-saml2-core, version=1.0.0.RC2, type=jar}).
[WARNING] File to remove [/Users/davea/Documents/my_workspace/my-module/target/my-module/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.0.RC2.jar] has not been found
[INFO] Dependency [Dependency {groupId=org.opensaml, artifactId=opensaml, version=2.6.1, type=jar}] has changed (was Dependency {groupId=org.opensaml, artifactId=opensaml, version=2.6.1, type=jar}).
[WARNING] File to remove [/Users/davea/Documents/my_workspace/my-module/target/my-module/WEB-INF/lib/opensaml-2.6.1.jar] has not been found
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/Users/davea/Documents/my_workspace/my-module/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [5454 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /Users/davea/Documents/my_workspace/my-module/target/my-module.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18.1:verify (default) @ my-module ---
[INFO] Failsafe report directory: /Users/davea/Documents/my_workspace/my-module/target/failsafe-reports
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:17 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-09T11:23:47-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 48M/792M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18.1:verify (default) on project my-module: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/davea/Documents/my_workspace/my-module/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: The fact that your build packages a war should not impact your pipeline. The build is clearly marked as a failure, and that should prevent any subsequent actions taking place. Could you not just ignore the war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified any phase(s) you want `failsafe` plugin to run its goals on. By default, the goals `integration-test` and `verify` are bound to the `integration-test` and `verify` phases of the `default` life cycle.

Recall that these phases occur after the `package` phase is complete (refer [the life cycle references](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)), so with the configuration you have, you are not impacting the `package` phase in any way - your goals run after the `package` phase (i.e the goals set to run in that phase - the `maven-war-plugin:2.6:war` being one) is complete.

You could try running the integration tests and verifying them before the `package` phase if that's what you really want by specifying the appropriate phase(s) for your goals in the `<execution>` you've shown in your OP.

---

Unrelated to the problem, the `maven-failsafe-plugin` plugin is intended to target integration tests and decouple the build failures from the actual integration test results.  You get around it by verifying your integration test results.

Here's a quote from the [FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/faq.html#surefire-v-failsafe):

> What is the difference between maven-failsafe-plugin and
>   maven-surefire-plugin?
>
> `maven-surefire-plugin` is designed for running unit tests and if any of the tests fail then it will fail the build immediately.
>
> `maven-failsafe-plugin` is designed for running integration tests, and decouples failing the build if there are test failures from
>   actually running the tests.

Further [notes](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) on this subject:

> If you use the Surefire Plugin for running tests, then when you have a
>   test failure, the build will stop at the integration-test phase and
>   your integration test environment will not have been torn down
>   correctly.
>
> The Failsafe Plugin is used during the integration-test and verify
>   phases of the build lifecycle to execute the integration tests of an
>   application. The Failsafe Plugin will not fail the build during the
>   integration-test phase, thus enabling the post-integration-test phase
>   to execute.

Comment: Removed my answer as it was similar to yours.